# Decimal to Binary Converter (Whole numbers 1-8)

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

Number 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 keep returning incorrect values such as 20, 21, and 31. Can anyone help? Thanks! I am trying to convert decimal numbers to binary numbers and am working with whole numbers, 1-8.

```
// This program converts whole numbers from 1 to 8 to their binary equivalent.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int decimal;
    int binary;
    int remainder1;
    int remainder2;
    int remainder3;
    int remainderA;
    int remainderB;
    int remainderC;
// Get the decimal to convert.
cout << "Enter a whole number between 1 and 8: ";
cin >> decimal;

if (decimal==1)
{
        binary = decimal/1;
        cout << binary;
    }
else if (2 <= decimal < 4)
{
        remainder1=decimal%2;
        remainderA=decimal/2;
        binary=remainder1/1;
        cout << remainderA <<binary;
    }
else if (4 <= decimal < 8)
{
        remainder2=decimal%4;
        remainderA=decimal/4;
        remainder1=remainder2%2;
        remainderB=remainder2/2;
        binary=remainder1/1;
        cout << remainderA <<remainderB <<binary;
    }
else if(decimal==8)
{
        remainder3=decimal%8;
        remainderA=decimal/8;
        remainder2=remainder3%4;
        remainderB=remainder3/4;
        remainder1=remainder2%2;
        remainderC=remainder2/2;
        binary=remainder1/1;
        cout <<remainderA<<remainderB<<remainderC<<binary<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions like `2 <= decimal < 4`, whilst valid syntactically, do not do what you think they do.

Rewrite as `2 <= decimal && decimal < 4`.

Formally, `2 <= decimal < 4` is evaluated as `(2 <= decimal) < 4` due to *associativity*. This is either `true < 4` or `false < 4`, which evalues to `true` in both cases. This explains why your code breaks down from 4 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your test `if(4 <= decimal < 8)` is not what you meant,
you need to write `if((4 <= decimal) && (decimal < 8))`

What `if(4<= decimal < 8)` means is:

- declare an intermediary variable (call it `value`)
- 1) compare 4 with decimal, if decimal <= 4 then value = 1 else value
  = 0
- 2) if(value < 8) then ...